# Javascript alert value after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why I can't alert x value after this ajax request?
I work with error function.

```
           var x;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + code,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { 
           console.log('Result 1: ');
           console.log(data.responseText);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            var text = e.responseText;

            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

            var titleXml = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
            var contentXml = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('content')[0];

            title = titleXml.childNodes[0];
            content = contentXml.childNodes[0];

            x = title;

        }
    });

    alert(x);
```

if I make alert local in error function everything work fine, but I need to alert x value after ajax.

Comment: You can't cause the ajax call is asynchronies

Comment: not without changing the ajax settings, i.e. not by doing the call as the question was asked. In his question the call is made asynchronous. Thats why he can't!

Answer (score 2):

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + code,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { 
           console.log('Result 1: ');
           console.log(data.responseText);
            alert(x);
//          ^^^^^^^^when get any success then use alert on ajax success
        },
        error: function(e) {
            var text = e.responseText;

            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

            var titleXml = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
            var contentXml = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('content')[0];

            title = titleXml.childNodes[0];
            content = contentXml.childNodes[0];

            x = title;
            alert(x); 
//          ^^^^^^^^when get any error then use alert on ajax error  

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks :) @LubomurMarshal feel happy its works for you

Answer (score 1):

The error or success functions are called in case of error or success of Ajax Request when it completes so the code that assigns the value to x would not have executed if you alert the value outside the functions.

The value of x is assigned after the request is completed so it works in case you have it alerted inside the error function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please :

```
           var x;

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + code,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { 
       x = 0;
       console.log('Result 1: ');
       console.log(data.responseText);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        var text = e.responseText;

        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

        var titleXml = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
        var contentXml = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('content')[0];

        title = titleXml.childNodes[0];
        content = contentXml.childNodes[0];

        x = title;

    }
});

alert(x);
```

What is your error ?

Comment: 0, of course - this is asynchronous.

Comment: @Ian wrong, the alert will state `undefined`.

Comment: Doh, read it too fast @Christoph. You're right. +1 for the spot.